# Does $Z^2$ always mean $ZZ^*$ in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation, complex-numbers

So I was listening to video on quantum mechanics and the following happened:

$$ |c\rangle = a|x\rangle + b|y\rangle$$

This was for polarized light, where $a$ and $b$ were probability amplitudes. The state $c$ was for circularly polarized light (clockwise). The video suggested:

$$ a = 1 ~\mathrm{and}~ b = i $$

But $a$ and $b$ also had to fit the parameter of:

$$ a^2+b^2=1 $$

And if you normally did such an operation with 1 and $i$, you would get 0. But then the video stated "what we really mean when we say squaring, is the value multiplied by its complex conjugate". My question is whether this rule applies everywhere in quantum mechanics? Does every value squared really mean it is being multiplied by its complex conjugate or it is unique to this example? Basically I need clarification whether this is case specific or used always in QM.

The video link is: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNMzUf5GZsQ&index=23&list=PL04722FAFB07E38E1)
If you watch it, I used different variables for the probability amplitudes and CP state. Also this happened around 45 min.

Comment: There is no general statement that squaring always means absolute value squared in quantum mechanics. Both operations appear and it is important to distinguish them. The video is just creating more confusion by saying this. I will note however that in the context that you have currently presented, you do mean take product or quantity with its complex conjugate.

Comment: Prahar, I don't recall saying that squaring means absolute value squared in QM. And I do mean the products of the value and its complex conjugate. I didn't want to put the sign lest people get confused for the conjugate sign. Thanks for asking and letting me clarify.

Comment: As an exercise, find the difference between the absolute value squared and value times complex conjugate of value.   But @Prahar is correct.  You have to be careful to figure out the meaning from context.

Comment: @genius - I thought that was your question since you wrote "_My question is whether this rule applies everywhere in quantum mechanics? Does every value squared really mean it is being multiplied by its complex conjugate or it is unique to this example?_" All I am saying is that this rule does not apply everywhere.

Comment: @genius - PS - multiplying a quantity with its complex conjugate is by definition, the absolute value squared.